# Error while using react-animations library within a Gatsby JS website

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gatsby, react-animations

I created a Gatsby JS website and I would like to use some simple animations for the text. The library 'react-animations' is the library I chose for the scope.

When installing it with

```
npm i --save react-animations
```

I get the following messages:

> npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@4.0.1 requires a peer of
>   eslint-plugin-flowtype@2.x but none is installed. You must install
>   peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN ts-pnp@1.1.4 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of > typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

By trying to use the library this way:

```
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components'
import { slideInDown } from 'react-animations'

const slideInDownAnimation = keyframes`${slideInDown}`;

const slideDown = styled.div`
  animation: 2s ${slideInDownAnimation};
`
;
```

It doesn't work and I get the following message when the import is located:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-animations'.
>   'c:path/node_modules/react-animations/lib/index.js' implicitly has an
>   'any' type.   Try `npm install @types/react-animations` if it exists
>   or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module
>   'react-animations';`

I tried

```
npm install @types/react-animations
```

But it doesn't exist.

Any clue on how to solve? Is typescript needed?

Thanks a lot.